# Changing the data-range of an existing PowerPoint-Chart using vba

Tags: excel, vba, charts, powerpoint

I'm trying to do the following using vba:

I automatically gather data in Excel and want to paste it in an existing PowerPoint-Chart.

It is working fine, that's the way i do it (the paste-to-powerpoint-part):

```
Dim myChart As PowerPoint.Chart
Dim myChart As PowerPoint.Chart
Dim myData As PowerPoint.ChartData
Dim myWkb As Excel.Workbook
Dim myWks As Excel.Worksheet
Dim wbcd As Workbook  

For chnmb = 1 To 1000
    On Error Resume Next
    Set myChart = ppSlide.Shapes(chnmb).Chart
    'test_name = myChart.Name
    If myChart.Name = "" Then Else Exit For
Next
```

I am doing this above (surely not the perfect way) because I don't know the Chart-Name (it is supposed to work for different Charts in different ppt-Files). After that:

```
Set myData = myChart.ChartData
Set myWkb = myData.Workbook
Set myWks = myWkb.Worksheets(1)

dat_area = "A1:" & Cells(1 + rowct, 1 + colct).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)

myWks.ListObjects(1).Resize myWks.Range(dat_area)
```

That is the part not working.

I manage to fill data into the Chart using:

```
myWks.Cells(j, i).Value = Workbooks("ppt-tool.xlsm").Sheets("Acc_Data").Cells(Row + j, 1 + i).Value
```

(via for-next; I don't want to paste the data but fill in every field) and to later edit the Chart, but it won´t change the data-area (with the blue border around it) of the ppt-Chart.

Strangely, if I create a new Chart using

```
Set myChart = ppSlide.Shapes.AddChart2(297, xlBarStacked100).Chart
```

I manage to resize the data area (with the same resize-code), but it's not working with existing Charts. Incidentally, I don't want to link the ppt-Chart to Excel (because the Excel-Tool is used over and over again with no data saved and the ppt-Charts may have to be edited later again).

Comment: To find the chart (shape) name in 2010:  select the chart, select _Format_ from the _Chart Tools_, select _Selection Pane_ from _Arrange_.

Comment: Hi, first of all, thx for your answer! But the Problem i can't solve is the Problem with the data-range. The finding of the chart-Name isn't that important, since I found a (not really good, but working) way to solve this (any advice here is welcome, too!), and it has to be solved using vba.

Comment: I was looking at some of my old code to see if I could come up with an answer for you.  I think it depends on how the chart is added to PPT.  I think I added the chart as an _Object_ on the Insert ribbon.  The right-click menu on the chart then gives you "Chart Object" with a sub-menu to edit it, whereas inserting a chart gives pretty much the same menu as Excel.  I could then reference the worksheet using `Set oWrkSht = oSlide.Shapes("Object 2").OLEFormat.Object.Worksheets(1)`.  Haven't got time to test it all at the moment, so haven't answered properly.

Comment: Hi, that's not working (or I'm doing it wrong). The Chart was added using the ppt-insert-ribbon, afaik. The strange Thing is that I can Change the data of the ppt-Chart (using f.e. 'myWks.Cells(j, i).Value='), only the range of data won't Change. If I have a Chart (BarStacked100) with 9 bars and I insert data for 7 bars (working fine), the other 2 bars will remain.

Comment: I can remember from my project having trouble with the charts updating and I ended up changing the view, then changing it back.  Try this code:  `Private Sub RefreshChart(oPPT As Object, SlideNum As Long, sh As Object): On Error Resume Next: oPPT.ActiveWindow.viewtype = 7: oPPT.ActiveWindow.View.GoToSlide SlideNum: oPPT.ActiveWindow.viewtype = 9: sh.OLEFormat.DoVerb (1): On Error GoTo 0: End Sub`.  I should try and test/expand these comments into a full answer over the bank holiday weekend.

Comment: Thanks! To be honest, I don't really know how to implement this in my code above... :-(

Comment: Sorry, yes, should have explained that part.  After changing the data for the chart call the `RefreshChart` procedure passing it a reference to the application, the slide number and the shape object.  But, yet again, this may rely on how the chart was added.

Comment: OK, now it's getting really confusing. If I use an existing Chart (stacked bar 100) with f.e. 4 bars and I have data for 7 bars, the resize won't work (the data itself is added). But if I use an existing Chart with f.e. 9 bars, the resize is working.Thus the resize works when reducing the data-area, but it's not working when expanding the data-area. That seems totally strange?!